# Is there a way to exclude a project from being logged?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I have an app where sometimes I'd like to log in `Debug` mode.  Unfortunately i link with a third party lib that I can't rebuild.  It was built to use `log4net` and on the `Debug` mode it is very verbose.

I don't want to get any notifications from that library.  I do however want to get log notifications from all other code that wants to write.

Is there a way to exclude a namespace or library from logging when using either the `SMTPAppender` or `RollingFile Appender` writers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a filter, e.g.

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
  <!-- allows this sub-namespace to be logged... -->
  <loggerToMatch value="Noisy.Namespace.But.Important" />
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
  <!-- ...but not the rest of it -->
  <loggerToMatch value="Noisy.Namespace" />
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```

More details from this [article](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2009/06/log4net-filtering-by-logger.html).

Answer (score 1):

Im imagine that you are using a configuration where you set only the root level of your logging infrastructure:

```
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="A1" />
</root>
```

However it is possible to define other levels of logging using the logger names. If you or the third party app followed standard practices, your loggers are named after the class they live with its namespace, so you will have loggers called

- MyApp.Main
- MyApp.Business
- MyApp.Business.Messages
- ThirdParty.API
- etc...

What you can do in this case is declare the logging at the namespace level you're interested in. For example to log only what lives under `MyApp.Main` add the following

```
<logger name="MyApp.Main">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="A1" />
</logger>
```

and remove any appender from the `root` level. Then you only log the loggers that live under the `MyApp` name. See [the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) for more info.

If you are unlucky and the loggers don't conform to this hierarchy, you can still filter them out by using a [LoggerMatchFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter.html) in your appender; this lets you either define what logger can pass, or what loggers cannot. There are lots of [filters](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.FilterSkeleton.html), feel free to explore them

Comment: Yes I can do this. but there are many other third party libraries I'd like to keep logging.  I'm looking for more of an exclusion rule than an inclusion rule.  The filtering you suggest looks promising.

Comment: Indeed if you have multiple logger hierarchies, it is more annoying to customize them all. The `LoggerMatchFilter` is a much better solution in this case